# How to run tflint rules all at one for a specific provider?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I installed the tflint plugin but when I run tflint on the root module I get nothing. When I specify a rule with --enable-rule then I get some warnings. How can I run the ruleset of azure or aws all at once?

Comment: That's not possible. The rationale from tflint's authors is that some rules require configuration and other rules are too strict so they've opted for only enabling the bare minimum, which I find unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to azure you can install the plugin by adding a config to .tflint.hcl and running tflint --init:

```
plugin "azurerm" {
    enabled = true
    version = "0.14.0"
    source  = "github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm"
}
```

If you want to add a new rule to this ruleset, you can use the generator

```
$ go run ./rules/generator
```

You can find the list of rules available for the tflint-ruleset-azurerm [Here](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-azurerm)